# When running Pytest tests individually - they pass. When running all the last one fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

This is my structure:

```
.
├── EmployeeApp
├── accounts
└── tests/
    ├── accounts/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_views.py
    ├── EmployeeApp/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_views.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── conftest.py
```

This is the tests/EmployeeApp/test_views module and the last test is the failing one:

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


client = APIClient()
MOCK_COMPANY_RESPONSE = {'company_name': 'Test Company',
                         'company_description': 'comp descr',
                         'company_logo': 'logo.asd'}



@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_company_list_view(register_and_login_user):
    token = register_and_login_user.data['token']

    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)

    data = {'company_name': 'Test Company',
            'company_description': 'comp descr',
            'company_logo': 'logo.asd'
            }
    client.post('/api/companies', data=data, format='json')
    request = client.get('/api/companies/', format='json')
    assert len(request.data) == 1
    assert request.status_code == 200


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_company_create(register_and_login_user):
    token = register_and_login_user.data['token']

    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)

    data = {'company_name': 'Test Company',
            'company_description': 'comp descr',
            'company_logo': 'logo.asd'
            }
    request = client.post('/api/companies', data=data, format='json')

    assert request.data == {'company_name': 'Test Company',
                            'company_description': 'comp descr',
                            'company_logo': 'logo.asd'}
    assert request.status_code == 201


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_own_company_info_successful(register_and_login_user, create_company):
    token = register_and_login_user.data['token']

    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)

    comp = create_company

    request = client.get('/api/companies/1/', format='json')

    assert request.data == MOCK_COMPANY_RESPONSE
```

These are the fixtures in `conftest.py` that I am passing:

```
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


client = APIClient()


@pytest.fixture
def register_and_login_user():
    payload = {
        "username": "testuser",
        "email": "email@mail.com",
        "password": "12345678"
    }

    client.post("/api/auth/signup", payload)
    login_response = client.post("/api/auth/login", {"email": "email@mail.com",
                                                     "password": "12345678"})
    return login_response


@pytest.fixture
def create_company():
    payload = {
        "username": "testuser",
        "email": "email@mail.com",
        "password": "12345678"
    }

    client.post("/api/auth/signup", payload)
    login_response = client.post("/api/auth/login", {"email": "email@mail.com",
                                                     "password": "12345678"})

    token = login_response.data['token']

    client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)

    data = {
            'company_name': 'Test Company',
            'company_description': 'comp descr',
            'company_logo': 'logo.asd'
            }
    request = client.post('/api/companies', data=data, format='json')
    return request


@pytest.fixture
def login():
    login = client.post("/api/auth/login", {"email": "email@mail.com",
                                            "password": "12345678"})
    token = login.data['token']
    return client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)
```

When I run it with `pytest -k test_get_own_company_info_successful` it passes.

When I run `pytest` all the tests pass, but this one with assertion error:

[image]

I think it fails to register a user, thus failing to also create a company and call it. What am I missing here?

I tried rearranging the tests and it has an effect on the run order when called with the pytest command.

For example if

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_company_create(register_and_login_user):
```

is below

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_own_company_info_successful(register_and_login_user, create_company):
```

When re-arranged, both fail to create a user in the database and give the bad request warning:

WARNING  django.request:log.py:241 Bad Request: /api/auth/signup

I am using

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
```

decorator, so tests should be independent of each other and the test database should be created and deleted after each individual test, but apparently they are somehow intertwined and I can't figure out how.

Would greatly appreciate it if somebody has some input on this!

Comment: add __init__.py file in tests folder